# KDE5 Plasma: Move maximized window with title hidden by grabbing top application menu panel

Tags: kde, gui

I would like to have unity like (macos like) top panel. I added top app menu bar then installed  this plugin https://store.kde.org/p/1272871/. It shows buttons and allows to remove title and borders when window is maximized.

But when window is maximized it's also wanted to move it by clicking and holding mouse on it's header which is now represented by this top panel. How to this? Is it possible? It looks like if spacer between app menu and system tray handles mouse in such a special way.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I want the same thing, but it is only possible using Latte-dock. Since Latte-dock has got too many bugs I've switched to plasma default panel, and I miss this drag from panel functionality, so I'm now just using the Active Window Control function where I can scroll to unmaximize a window.

Comment: I use latte, It works fine for me

Comment: @4xy if using Latte Dock is the solution for you, you may want to add an answer saying so to help future visitors